# Parse dynamically created XML document in c#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have to parse an XML document like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <DialsList>
      <Dial>
        <Id>123</Id>
        <Source>SQL</Source>
        <Server>myServer</Server>
        <Database>myDB</Database>
        <UserName>myUserName</UserName>
        <Password>myPassword</Password>
        <TableName>myTable</TableName>
        <Query>GetAvgForUser</Query>
        <Parameters>
          <Param1>
            <Name>@DialId</Name>
            <Type>Int</Type>
          </Param1>
          <Param2>
            <Name>@UserId</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
          </Param2>
        </Parameters>
      </Dial>
      <Dial>
    <Id>789</Id>
    <Source>SQL</Source>
    <Server>someServer</Server>
    <Database>someDB</Database>
    <UserName>someUser</UserName>
    <Password>somePwd</Password>
    <TableName>someTbl</TableName>
    <Query>someQry</Query>
    <Parameters>
      <Param1>
        <Name>@myParam</Name>
        <Type>Int</Type>
      </Param1>
      <Param2>
        <Name>@anotherParam</Name>
        <Type>String</Type>
      </Param2>
    </Parameters>
  </Dial>
    </DialsList>
```

My application has to read this XML document and form the connection string as well as execute the query/storedprocedure specified in the `<Query>` node. I have no problems forming the connectionstring. Since it can be any stored procedure and it can have any number of `parameters`,I cannot figure out a way to parse this XML. The XML will be dynamic - parameters,parameter names,parameter type,etc. and it's not under my control. I have this code so far which works if there's only 1 Parameter(I'm assuming it will be "int"):

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
    string dialID = Convert.ToString(DialId);
    XElement DialsDoc = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants("Dial")                       where xml2.Element("Id").Value == dialID                                              select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
    dialDataSrc.Source = DialsDoc.Element("Source").Value.ToString();
    if (dialDataSrc.Source.ToString() == "SQL")
    {
        DataSource dialDataSrc = new DataSource();
        dialDataSrc.MethodNameIndividual = string.Empty;
        dialDataSrc.MethodNameGroup = string.Empty;
        dialDataSrc.Server = DialsDoc.Element("Server").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.Database = DialsDoc.Element("Database").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.Username = DialsDoc.Element("UserName").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.Password = DialsDoc.Element("Password").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.TableName = DialsDoc.Element("TableName").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.Query = DialsDoc.Element("Query").Value.ToString();
        dialDataSrc.Parameters = DialsDoc.Element("Parameters").Value.ToString();
    }
```

I then form the connection string and execute the stored procedure.
How do I go about handling this when it's dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out the Type of dialDataSrc but this should get you on your way:

```
var listOfparameters = DialsDoc
        .Element("Parameters")
        .Elements()
        .Select(p => MyCreateParam((string) p.Element("Name"), (string) p.Element("Type")))
        .ToList();
```

With a little helper method to figure out the DbType etc:

```
private SqlParameter MyCreateParam(string name, string _type) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks,I've added the helper method.However,I now get an error message: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type......" in the ".ToList()"

Comment: Did you check Element and Elements ? The arg for ToList should be an IEnumerable.

Comment: Apparently,the "Select" was missing a ')' at the end.